# How to use ViewData to change css for a specific view

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

So I'm having a view that uses a layout and I wanted to change the css for body for just him, and i stumbled upon this solution:

Top of my view:

```
@{
    ViewData["PageId"] = "Login";
}
```

Css:

```
body#Login {
    padding-top: 0;
    background: #000428;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #004e92, #000428);
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #004e92, #000428);
}
```

But when I decided I wanted to change the css for the html too, it didn't work?

```
html#Login {
     overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Can someone explain how that even works, and why can't there be any space between `body` and `#Login`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector requires the `body` tag having a Id called `Login` like this:

```
<body id="Login">
    This is the Target Element of your Selector
</body>
```

So if the body doesn't have this Id, the selector didn't match. A non-matching example could be this one:

```
<body>
    This element has no Id called Login and so Css wouldn't apply
</body>
```

You *could* overwrite the `body` with some additional Code, that's right. But keep in mind, that the order matters in CSS! So you've to include your second code *after* the original CSS code, which you want to overwrite. When the CSS is loaded in the `_Layout` file, you could use a section for example, to make sure that it's applied *after* the shared CSS to overwrite it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" rel="css/master-shared-stylesheet.css">
@RenderSection("AdditionalPageCss")
```

Then you can do something like this in the View, where you want to overwrite `master-shared-stylesheet.css`:

```
@section AdditionalPageCss {
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Overwrite */
        body {
            overflow-y: auto; 
        }
    </style>
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure we understood each other, if I simply write `body` than the css will be applied to every view that uses that layout. I want to apply css for the body ONLY for the login view, and I actually achieved that with `body#Login` - that works, but it doesn't work for the html css

Comment: Updated to be more clear. Keep in mind that your code only works when `body` has a Id called `Login`. So you need some kind of global variable to do this, like `ViewBag.BodyId`.

Comment: I think I understand now thank you :D Can you also clarify why it's written `body#Login` and not `body #Login`?

Comment: You meen the space? `body #Login` has a totally different meaning: It applys to an element with the Id `Login`, that has to be _inside_ the `body`element like this: `<body><div id="Login"></div></body>` So your structure doesn't work with this selector.